# SSH timeout to everywhere after a fresh RHEL7 install

Tags: ssh

```
[user@desktop ~]$ ssh root@foobar
...
$ sudo su -
[YOU HAVE NEW MAIL]
root@foobar:/home/root # cd /etc 
root@foobar:/etc # Connection to 1.2.3.4 closed by remote host.
Connection to 1.2.3.4 closed.
[user@desktop ~]$
```

After installing RHEL7 to my desktop (it was RHEL6 before and it worked perfectly).

**Question:** no matter where I ssh, it will always say, connection closed by remote host. a few seconds after login.. Why?? Before fresh install it worked perfectly.

UPDATE: "1) What happens if you run "telnet yourhost 22"." -> I did and telnet didn't closed the connection!

UPDATE#2:

```
[USER@DESKTOP applications]$ ssh -vvv USERONSERVER@SERVERNAME
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/USER/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/USER/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for dee1*
debug1: /home/USER/.ssh/config line 7: Applying options for dee1*
debug1: /home/USER/.ssh/config line 18: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 67: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to SERVERNAME [1.2.3.4] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/USER/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/USER/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/USER/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USER/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USER/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USER/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USER/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USER/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USER/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 1.99, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "SERVERNAME" from file "/home/USER/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/USER/.ssh/known_hosts:822
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: ecdh-sha2-nistp256 need=16 dh_need=16
debug1: kex: ecdh-sha2-nistp256 need=16 dh_need=16
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA censored
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "SERVERNAME" from file "/home/USER/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/USER/.ssh/known_hosts:822
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "1.2.3.4" from file "/home/USER/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/USER/.ssh/known_hosts:801
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host 'SERVERNAME' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/USER/.ssh/known_hosts:822
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/USER/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7fe5faa58140),
debug2: key: Created by SASGUI (0x7fe5faa589f0),
debug2: key: id_rsa (0x7fe5faa59040),
debug2: key: /home/USER/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/USER/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/USER/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/USER/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 148
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp censored
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA censored
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to SERVERNAME ([1.2.3.4]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug2: callback start
debug1: Requesting authentication agent forwarding.
debug2: channel 0: request auth-agent-req@openssh.com confirm 0
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env XDG_VTNR
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AGENT_PID
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env GUESTFISH_INIT
debug3: Ignored env HOSTNAME
debug3: Ignored env IMSETTINGS_INTEGRATE_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env GPG_AGENT_INFO
debug3: Ignored env VTE_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env XDG_MENU_PREFIX
debug3: Ignored env HISTSIZE
debug3: Ignored env GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWID
debug3: Ignored env QTDIR
debug3: Ignored env QTINC
debug3: Ignored env GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS
debug3: Ignored env IMSETTINGS_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM_CHECKED
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env SESSION_MANAGER
debug3: Ignored env USERNAME
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_DISABLE_CRASH_DIALOG
debug3: Ignored env GUESTFISH_PS1
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env DESKTOP_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env QT_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug1: Sending env XMODIFIERS = @im=ibus
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.utf8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env GDM_LANG
debug3: Ignored env KDEDIRS
debug3: Ignored env GUESTFISH_OUTPUT
debug3: Ignored env PD_SOCKET
debug3: Ignored env GDMSESSION
debug3: Ignored env HISTCONTROL
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SEAT
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env QTLIB
debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWPATH
debug3: Ignored env PDHOST
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env QT_PLUGIN_PATH
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env GUESTFISH_RESTORE
debug3: Ignored env XAUTHORITY
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0

censored - motd here - censored

$ sudo su -
[YOU HAVE NEW MAIL]
root@SERVERNAME:/home/root # date
Fri Apr 15 10:39:22 UTC 2016
root@SERVERNAME:/home/root # debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 fd 4/5 cc -1)

Connection to SERVERNAME closed by remote host.
Connection to SERVERNAME closed.
Transferred: sent 4240, received 4440 bytes, in 217.5 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 19.5, received 20.4
debug1: Exit status -1
[USER@DESKTOP applications]$
```

Comment: Can you add in the relevant lines after this happens with ssh-vv? One possibility is a (new?) TMOUT on the remote side.

Comment: no, not TMOUT problem. it happens to all servers. it is a client side problem. $TMOUT is 0 or 9999.

Comment: is the timing consistently around 217 seconds? It's interesting that your most recent/proximate change is RHEL6->RHEL7, but the message is that the connection was closed by the *remote* host. [This](http://superuser.com/questions/522094/how-do-i-resolve-a-ssh-connection-closed-by-remote-host-due-to-inactivity) refers to using a .ssh/config ServerAliveInterval parameter; does that change the behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HW was a T450. It turned out the wifi caused the problem. On ethernet cable, it worked perfectly.

```
echo 'options iwlmvm power_scheme=1' >> /etc/modprobe.d/iwlmvm.conf
cd /boot
cp initramfs-3.10.0-327.4.5.el7.x86_64.img initramfs-3.10.0-327.4.5.el7.x86_64.img.orig
dracut -v -f  initramfs-3.10.0-327.4.5.el7.x86_64.img  3.10.0-327.4.5.el7.x86_64
rebooot
```

Answer (score 0):

Do some troubleshooting:

1) What happens if you run "telnet yourhost 22".

this is what happens (with the proper IP of course):

> ```
>  Trying 1.2.3.4...
>  Connected to yourhost (1.2.3.4)
>  Escape character is '^]'.
>  Connection closed by foreign host.
> ```
>
> 2) How quickly does the "closed" occur?

I'd say 4/5 seconds

3) What is the output of "ssh -v yourhost"

Also check your keepalive seetings in sshd configuration file (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`).
set , TCPKeepAlive=yes

OR  try it using `ssh -o TCPKeepAlive=yes`

Comment: why 4/5 seconds ? do you know something? :)

Comment: updated the question

Comment: for more options , answer updated

Comment: you can also try this , by just disabling your firewall/iptables